# Android executing both IF and ELSE statement together

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am working with FireBase Notifications and I can send a notification which will send the user to the webview page I input on the console.

The problem is that when it matches the IF statement is fires the else statement too, what could be the cause of this?

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) {
    for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
        if (key.equals("url")){
            mwebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/" + getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));
        }else {
            mwebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Because it executes both at the same time the app crashes.

Also when I load the app the usual way it matches the with:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
```

and then loads the else statement. Shouldnt `getExtras` be `null`?

When I first install a new instance of the app it uses the following statement:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()==null) {
    if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
        mwebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
    } else {
        mwebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");
    }
}
```

*Update:*

As I cannot find out why this it happening I am trying another approach, How would I get the variable outside of the loop to use like the following:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) {
    for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
        String valuex = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
    }
}

if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
    mwebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/" + valuex);
} else {
    mwebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with executes at the same time? That´s not possible, for clearance, which if statement do you mean? `if(getIntent().getExtras()==null)` or `if (key.equals("url"))` ?

Comment: `if (key.equals("url"))`

Comment: you commented on michel´s answer, that you put a toast on both and that´s the cause that you know that both are executed. That suggests me, that the code posted in your question is not exactly the same. From my own experience I know, that some very little details can be overseen, so please post the complete code from your project and don´t leave something out....

Comment: From your posted Question, it´s absolutely IMPOSSIBLE that both are executed at the same time. The only thing that is possible is, that while you are looping the value `getIntent().getExtras().keySet()` has changed and the else statement is executed in one of the next loops

Comment: Do you think Google sends my Key/value along with a blank Key/value? the reason I say this as when I create a new notification there is a blank Key/value but I am not sure whether it is sending anything across. Instead of a loop how would I get the first Key/value?

Comment: why google? As far as I understand your question, you are sending the notification: **I can send a notification which will send the user to the webview page** ...maybe I haven´t understand you correct....

Comment: I guess you should add a `break` if one statement is reached to break the for loop. So only one statement can be executed.

Comment: I think this may have worked, kind of as it didnt crash the app but the notification didnt send me to the webview url. I put the toast before the if statements and I seen one blank toast. it was the first one which is strange. Is there anyway I could wrap it in... if( user came from notification ect) do this

Comment: what about check the value? Could be something like `String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)` and then `if(value!=null&&!value.isEmpty())` . So you can be sure you have no empty value and you can load the url

Comment: Regarding your update - how do you expect that to work? You have a loop that could result in many values, *which* value would you use in the code below the loop?

Comment: I only use one key and one value, do I even need a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If and Else can not both be executed in one go.

You should check your other code and ensure, that this code section is not executed twice for some reason (once with TRUE and once with FALSE).

Comment: I can assure you that both execute as I have added a Toast on both and it will show them both at once.

Comment: Yes, they can be both executed. But not in one go. Maybe that code section is being called twice.

Comment: Do you think Google sends my Key/value along with a blank Key/value? the reason I say this as when I create a new notification there is a blank Key/value but I am not sure whether it is sending anything across